# Unity TCP Server Hang Unity scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, tcplistener

I am trying to implement a TCP server in unity. I am using `unity pro 3.5` and when I run this code in a scene, then unity hang, no response at all untill I kill it with Task Manager.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;


public class Server : MonoBehaviour {

    private IPAddress ipAd;
    public string IP="127.0.0.1";
    public int port = 8001;
    private Socket s;

    void Update ()
    {   

    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
            port = 8001;
            ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
            msg = "Listening at " + IP + ":" + port.ToString();
            this.s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            this.s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAd,port));
            this.s.Listen(200);
            while (true)
              this.ReceiveMessage(this.s.Accept()); //hang if this line activated
    }
    private void ReceiveMessage(Socket socket)
        {
            byte[] tempbuffer = new byte[10000];
            socket.Receive(tempbuffer);
            rec.AssignFromByteArray(tempbuffer);                
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Server should run in it's own thread so the GameLoop can continue even if `tcp_Listener.AcceptSocket()` is a blocking call.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool mRunning;
    public static string msg = "";

    public Thread mThread;
    public TcpListener tcp_Listener = null;

    void Awake() {
        mRunning = true;
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Receive);
        mThread = new Thread(ts);
        mThread.Start();
        print("Thread done...");
    }

    public void stopListening() {
        mRunning = false;
    }

    void Receive() {
        tcp_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8001);
        tcp_Listener.Start();
        print("Server Start");
        while (mRunning)
        {
            // check if new connections are pending, if not, be nice and sleep 100ms
            if (!tcp_Listener.Pending()){
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            else {
                Socket ss = tcp_Listener.AcceptSocket();
                BonePos rec = new BonePos();
                byte[] tempbuffer = new byte[10000];
                ss.Receive(tempbuffer); // received byte array from client
                rec.AssignFromByteArray(tempbuffer); // my own datatype
            }
        }
    }

    void Update() {

    }

    void OnApplicationQuit() { // stop listening thread
        stopListening();// wait for listening thread to terminate (max. 500ms)
        mThread.Join(500);
    }
}
```

See [Related answer from answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12329/server-tcp-network-problem.html)

Comment: `mRunning` should be volatile. The variable is set by the Unity thread and read from the receive thread, so the access should be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

You get the hanging because of this:

```
while (true)
          this.ReceiveMessage(this.s.Accept()); //hang if this line activated
```

The entire process is stuck in this loop, so nothing else gets processed.

What you could do (though I would not recommend it) is to perform the action inside update() instead of an infinite loop.

what I suggest is to use something else to run your server instead of unity.

If you are creating a game server, you can use PUN (Photon Unity Networking) or write a standalone server in C#, or even an open-sourced server in python that matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of this statement:

```
while (true)
    this.ReceiveMessage(this.s.Accept());
```

And your server has to run in his own thread.

Answer (score 0):

Unity's engine is single threaded, and the life cycle methods of monobehaviours run synchronously in a predefined order. An infinite loop in one life cycle method will infinitely hang the program.

[Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) are one way that you can create infinite loops without hanging indefinitely. This use case would likely make use of [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)